# How can I stop this popup from appearing every time I click anywhere inside editor

Tags: python, spyder

[image]

Is there anyway I can stop this popup (image attached)?

Comment: Which mouse button are you clicking? I guess this is a context menu that appears when you click the right button

Comment: It appears when i press Left mouse button while it should do so only i press right button.